# compare string from data grid cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
string prodcode = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["productUniqueCode"].Value.ToString();
string prodCateogry = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["productCategory"].Value.ToString();


if (prodCateogry.Equals("Diamond"))
{                 

}
```

I want to compare prodCategory value if it contains string equals to "Diamond" or not. the column productCategory has a value "Diamond". But 'if' statement is showing the comparison false. How to compare then?

Comment: Maybe you've got spaces at the end. Try `if (prodCateogry.Trim().Equals("Diamond"))`

Comment: Have you used the debugger?

Comment: Use debuger set break point to find problems. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788

Comment: yes I've set debugger but while debugging it comes to if statement and then jump to else statement.

Comment: @SaeedurRehman: you know that you can inspect the values of all variables and even execute statements in the debugger? What are the value of `prodCateogry` and `prodcode` exactly?

Comment: yes @TimSchmelter I know that.

Comment: both have same value i.e Diamond

Comment: That's impossible. If they have the exact same value, it should enter the if part. Anyway,have you tried `if (prodCateogry=="Diamond")..`

Comment: its solved, I don't know what happened but I restarted visual studio and it works fine. However thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The string you are comparing might have a word in upper or lower case so it doesn't match the string. Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to match the case of words.

```
if (prodCateogry.Trim().Equals("Diamond",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{

}
```

Comment: Nothing happened. :(

Comment: @SaeedurRehman check the edit i have added `Trim()` function to remove extra spaces.

Comment: @SaeedurRehman What is value of `prodCateogry ` while debugging ?

Comment: value of prodCateogry = "Diamond"

Comment: its solved, I don't know what happened but I restarted visual studio and it works fine. However thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;i++)
           {
              if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow .Cells["ProductName"].Value.Equals ("Diamond"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows [i].Cells [1].Value .ToString ());
                }
           }
```

Comment: its solved, I don't know what happened but I restarted visual studio and it works fine. However thank you for your time.